# Android custom ListView layout problems

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

## Hi guys, I tried to learn how to use custom ListView by this [page](http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-titles-icons-counter/)

It works fine but I have problems with another options.

1. Cannot set margin to listItems
2. Cannot set backgro
3. Cannot set OnItemClickListener

---

## 1# Margin

First of all I'm trying to set margin between list items but nothing works. I try to set margin on RelativeLayout in rowlayout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    >
```

---

## 2# Background

I want to set background on whole screen under listView. I think I put black color on every View in every xml I found but nothing affect the background. I can change background of single list items, that's all.

```
android:background="#000000"
```

---

## 3#OnItemClickListener

My last problem is that I'm not able to set onItemClickListener. I have no idea how to set it if I don't have simply ListView but RelativeLayout with TextView etc.
I guess I have to use

```
setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
```

and after that

```
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
```

but I have no idea on which View I have to use this method.

## Files

---

## MyAdapter.java

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Model> modelsArrayList;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Model> modelsArrayList) {

        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, modelsArrayList);

        this.context = context;
        this.modelsArrayList = modelsArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // 1. Create inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // 2. Get rowView from inflater

        View rowView = null;
        if(!modelsArrayList.get(position).isGroupHeader()){
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);

            // 3. Get icon,title & counter views from the rowView
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_icon);
            TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            TextView counterView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_counter);

            // 4. Set the text for textView
            imgView.setImageResource(modelsArrayList.get(position).getIcon());
            titleView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
            counterView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getCounter());
        }
        else{
            //rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_header, parent, false);
           // TextView titleView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.header);
           // titleView.setText(modelsArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
            }


        // 5. retrn rowView
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

## Model.java

```
package com.example.sunny.katan;

/**
 * Created by Sunny on 15.09.14.
 */
public class Model{

    private int icon;
    private String title;
    private String counter;

    private boolean isGroupHeader = false;

    public Model(String title) {
        this(-1,title,null);
        isGroupHeader = true;
    }
    public Model(int icon, String title, String counter) {
        super();
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public String getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public boolean isGroupHeader() {
        return false;
    }

    public void setGroupHeader(boolean isGroupHeader) {
        this.isGroupHeader = isGroupHeader;
    }


//gettters & setters...
}
```

## main.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        // if extending Activity
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // 1. pass context and data to the custom adapter
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());

        // if extending Activity 2. Get ListView from activity_main.xml
        //ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // 3. setListAdapter
        //listView.setAdapter(adapter); if extending Activity
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private ArrayList<Model> generateData(){
        ArrayList<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>();
        models.add(new Model(R.raw.barbell,"Cviky","37"));
        models.add(new Model(R.raw.stretching,"Protahování","94"));
        models.add(new Model(R.raw.work,"Generování workoutu","293"));

        return models;
    }
```

## rowlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    >

    <!-- icon -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@raw/barbell"
        />

    <!-- title -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item_icon"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/item_counter"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />

    <!-- counter -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_counter"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

## main.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    >


<LinearLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".katan_lobby"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#238CD4"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/prvniItemSeznamu"
        android:background="#238CD4"
        style="@style/listView"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Where is the listview on the XML? Are you adding it somewhere in code?

Comment: I added main.xml to my question. Where i declare ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are half way there in your activity.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, generateData());
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.menu);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); if extending Activity

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            //You now have the position but you will need to get your model list and use .get(position) and cast it to Model to get access to it.
        } 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//First define your list view item xml… something like this.

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/custom_blue"
        android:text="TextView" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="@color/custom_grey"
        android:text="TextView" />

     </LinearLayout> 

//Then you define your list list adapter.


    public class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyModel> {

    private Context            context;
    private ArrayList<MyModel> myModel;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyModel> myModelList) {
        super(context, R.id.icon, myModelList);

        this.context = context;
        this.myModelList = myModelList;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        View rowView = convertView;

            TextView myItemName = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.item1);
            TextView myItemTitle = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.item2);


           //use your models getters/setters
            myItemName.setText(myModelList.get(position).getItemTitle());
            myItemTitle.setText(myModelList.get(position).getItemName());
       return rowView
      }
    }

//Now use both the list adapter and list item in your ListFragment or ListActivity.

       ArrayList<MyModel> myModelList = new ArrayList<MyModel>();

        MyListAdapter myApt = new MyListAdapter(this, myModelList);
        setListAdapter(myApt);


     //For clicking on the items:
      @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // ListView Clicked item value
        String itemValue = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        doSomethingWihtMyItemMethod(position);
    }


 /* You can customize your list item anyway you like, just be aware of screen real estate  when doing so.Hope this helps.  */
```